# Filtering image gallery from file attributes and tags?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter, gallery, image-gallery

I don't know if this is possible, but I'm developing an image gallery that should draw upon a directory of a thousand or so photos. The naming convention doesn't allow for certain special characters, so artist names and piece names are applied as attributes to the image file.

Is there a way to filter my gallery by getting that data? I will most likely be implementing a search bar, but my options for altering the naming convention are very low.

I am limited to HTML, CSS, jQuery/JS

For example, a piece might have the naming convention:

```
bobross-prettytree-01.jpg
```

With [shortname]-[shorttitle]-[series#]

Whereas in the actual file, the attributes are

Robert Ross - Pretty Tree #1 - date - location

For displaying names with apostrophes or hyphens (the obvious delim here), I would need the data from the attributes.

Is this possible? I wish I could use PHP.

Comment: You could by the use of an extension or plugin that allows local file access (see Tiddly Wiki for an example) but this is not suitable for anything but local use.  The better solution is to have a web server running php or java or something that can serve the meta data via ajax to your web page.

Comment: Thanks J, you think something [this](https://www.bram.us/2016/02/18/read-exif-thumbnail-from-jpg-image-using-javascript/) would work? As long as the EXIF data can be interpreted on my end, I'm happy.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what you want.  The files will need to reside on the same machine that the web page runs on as this will open a local file reader in the browser.  If you want to share this on a website for remote users, I believe you'll need something different.